# Вывод данных из таблицы за определённую дату

Tags: php, mysql

на сайте есть форма с выбором даты и кнопка. По нажатию кнопки нужно, чтобы выводились записи из бд за выбранную в форме дату. Не знаю как правильно использовать ajax в этом примере.
Вот форма.

```
<label for="example-date-input" class="col-form-label">Дата</label>
                        <form method="post" name="delivery_date" action="func3.php" >
                        <input class="form-control" name="delivery_date" type="date" value="2019-03-22" id="example-date-input">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info mb-3">Поиск</button>
                        </form>
```

Вот php, к которому он обращается.

```
function get_date()
{
    global $link;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE delivery_date = '{$_POST['delivery_date']}' AND delivery = '1'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $users = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $users;
}
```

Как правильно подключить ajax к кнопке, чтобы вывод происходил по нажатию?

Answer (score 0):

Выдернкул кусок script`a из кода из своего проекта и подправил под твой. Должно работать

```
 var contactForm = $("form");
          contactForm.on("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var date_input = $("#example-date-input").val();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "func3.php",
              data: {
                delivery_date: date_input
              },
              success: function(response) {
                $('.result-form').html(response);

              }
            })
          });
```

.result-form это твой div или что там у тебя, куда будешь выводить данные.